# ways to create backup for azuresql

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-blob-storage

I want to create a backup for azure SQL databases that are not currently used to some low-cost storage account. I don't want to pay for those dbs as no operation are done on them. But I might need that data in the future. Extraction time is not an issue. So just want to know what are the different methods to do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood the question correctly then I would suggest for that database which you might not need immediately you can take back on azure blob storage.
There is a good blog for it 
https://dallasdbas.com/sql-backups-azure-storage/

Just follow it.
Hope this will help you.